# scheme, height and pstorder tree.

Tags: scheme

Consider an implementation of binary trees with Scheme lists, as in the following
example: 
[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbWzW.jpg) <-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1) The height of a tree is defined as the maximum number of nodes on a path from
the root to a leaf. Write a recursive function (height T)

> (height T)
>   4

2) Write a recursive function (postorder T), which returns the list of all
elements in the tree T corresponding to a postorder traversal of the tree.

> (postorder T)
>   (1 9 8 5 17 25 22 13)

for the first one: i only can get the total nodes, but not the height. 
second one i got no idea how to do it.

just start the scheme this week from C++

any tips or solution?

Comment: In case you've missed them: [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) and [HtDP](http://htdp.org/) are good free books.

Answer (score 0):

The height is 0 if it is the empty tree, eg. like the children of the node with `1` in your tree. For all other nodes its `1` plus the maxmimum of the heights of the children. A skeleton of the code might look like this:

```
(define (height tree)
  (if (eq? *tree-null* tree)
      ...
      (max (height ...)
           (height ...))))
```

For postorder you need to traverse again:

```
(define (postorder tree)
  (if (eq? *tree-null* tree)
      ...
      (append (postorder ...) 
              (porstorder ...) 
              (list (tree-value tree)))))
```

Notice how the two are very similar? One might make an abstraction:

```
(define (accumulate-tree tree combiner null-value)
  (let rec ((tree tree))
    (if (eq? *tree-null* tree) 
        null-value
        (combiner (tree-value tree)
                  (rec (tree-left tree)) 
                  (rec (tree-right tree))))))

(define (height tree)
  (accumulate-tree tree (lambda (v l r) (+ 1 l r)) 0))

(define (postorder tree)
  (accumulate-tree tree (lambda (v l r) (append l r (list v))) '()))
```